# Cmd cant find Hadoop after Pig Install

Tags: command-line, hadoop, installation, apache-pig

After installing pig, I can't call hadoop from the command line anymore.

ex:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Hadoop\Karung>hadoop version
'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here's a look at my `Path`:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\;C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\bat_files;C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Hadoop\hadoop-0.23.8\bin;C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Pig\pig-0.11.1\bin
```

Also I have the Hadoop, Pig, and Java install variables like so:

`HADOOP_INSTALL` `C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Hadoop\hadoop-0.23.8`

`PIG_INSTALL` `C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Pig\pig-0.11.1`

`JAVA_HOME` `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`

Everything seems to be setup correctly. They all execute when I run the commands from their directories. Why can't the command line recognize hadoop? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

`hadoop` is a bash script.  The Windows command-line doesn't know how to run this.

**Long answer**

You're going to need a lot more set up if you want to run Hadoop on Windows.  There are a number of tutorials out there, but honestly your best bet is to run it on a unix machine or VM.

[Installing Hadoop on Windows](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html)

[Cloudera QuickStart VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera+QuickStart+VM)

Comment: @climbage, Thanks for you suggestion +1. You were 100% right. I tried to install hadoop on windows for most of the afternoon using the tutorial you provided and many others with no luck. To anyone else trying I suggest that you also run a VM or dualboot your machine.

Comment: besides the download, the Cloudera VM was instant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just targeting windows, You could even run Hadoop and Pig on top of [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) to avoid the hassle of workarounds and problems or better to use [Hortonworks Data Platform or HDP](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/) that could be installed in windows directly.